# Bind an array from form parameters with springmvc

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, portlet

I'm trying to bind all the values of a checkbox in my Controller, here is some of my code.

```
<form method="post" action="${setDefaultArea}" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  <fieldset>

    <c:forEach var="area" items="${areas}" varStatus="status">
      <label for="area-${status.index}">
        <input type="checkbox" id="area-${status.index}" name="areas" value="${area}">
        ${area}
      </label>
    </c:forEach>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

And my controller

```
public void setDefaultArea(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response, @RequestParam(value="areas", required=true) String[] areas) throws Exception {
  System.out.println(areas);
}
```

And i'm stuck with this error : 
javax.portlet.PortletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'Required String[] parameter 'areas' is not present' for locale 'fr_FR'.

Could somebody give me a hand ? thanks !

Comment: Check you locale file for `fr_FR` with a key `areas`, if that is present?

Comment: It is not, but I thought it was only for the spring:message tag... what should I do ? :/

Comment: Please add the value to the file with key as `areas' and re-run

Comment: The thing is I don't understand why i got an error about a locale file... i just try to bind the value of my checkboxs in an array...

Comment: I couldn't able to answer you since i cannot get to know about completely with what is posted. I guess there is definitely someother part of the code throws it